# How to insert a space on the inside of braces with regex

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I'd like to insert spaces in a file <s>after and before</s> inside every `( ) [ ]` character. I'd like to use Sublime Edit's find and replace operation, but I'd guess all text editors would work the same.

For a single query I've constructed this:

find: `([\[\(])(\S)`

replace with: `$1 $2`

Of course I can construct two queries and run them in sequence, but I was planning to save it as a quick snippet I can apply for all files to make braces easier to read.

Is there any way to make multiple regex find-replace operations run at the same time?

How does the numbering ($1, $2, etc.) happen in an OR query? Or is it totally dependent on the text editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might like this:

Find regex: `(\[|\()\s*(.*?)\s*(\]|\))`
Replace with `$1 $2 $3`
Explained demo here: http://regex101.com/r/hF5uI5

OR

Find regex: `([\[\(])\s*|\s*([\]\)])`
Replace with `$1 $2`
Explained demo here: http://regex101.com/r/vA2aH3

Comment: Sorry, I'd only like to put a space inside the braces/brackets, not outside. So I'd like to have my formatting:
test(option)with[something]done => test( option )with[ something ]done

Comment: Thanks, I've update the first post as well as the name of the question. The first solution is really logical to me!

Comment: You're welcome. The second is actually better as it doesn't capture the insides!

Answer (score 0):

For even single space padding:

**version #1: one ( two ) [ three ] four**

pattern - `([ ]+)?([\[\]\(\)])([ ]+)?`

replacement - " `$2` "

**version #2: one( two )[ three ]four** *(learned a thing or two from ka ᵠ ;)*

pattern: `\s*([\[\(])\s*([^\]\)]*?)\s*([\]\)])\s*`

replacement: "`$1 $2 $3`"

**version #3: one (two) [three] four**

pattern: `\s*([\[\(])\s*([^\]\)]*?)\s*([\]\)])\s*`

replacement: "`$1$2$3`"

Also glad to discover the [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/).

Comment: +1 for the effort! v2 is what he needs here but `\s*` aren't needed before and after

Comment: @kaᵠ - thanks. yeah, it helps me learn. I am still trying to figure out how to get rid of the double spacing between two and three [here](http://regex101.com/r/iY4iX3). Really want to figure this out.

Comment: @kaᵠ, hooooold on!, if i did that, it was by accident - me switching between windows of stackoverflow and regex101 and second, even if it was copied, it was not copied right in the replacement part.

Comment: the link in the second comment is what I meant to change it to.

Comment: yeah, sorry. i am not a looser

Comment: and i am not yet done with my answer, want to get the extra spaces fixed

Comment: haha, i guess i am a looser ;), can't figure what i mentioned in comment #2 here. getting late, have to come back to it at some other time

Comment: no reason to say that! read the docs and you'll get a better grasp of regex. also please delete the useless comments here as we got carried on discussing and added no value at all